# Nginx ignores expires headers for sub-directories

Tags: nginx

I've compiled and installed nginx on my server (Fedora 21 x64).

I've added expires and some extra headers for static contents. But the thing is I nginx doesn't add expires and extra headers for root and sub-directories.

Let me explain that clearly.

mydomain.com/anything.html <-- Expires + Extra headers added.

mydomain.com/index.html --> (redirect) mydomain.com/ <-- No headers, no expires.

mydomain.com/projects/index.html --> (redirect) mydomain.com/projects/ <-- No headers, no expires.

I've configured my server to redirect /index.html to its parent sub-directory.

Here's the part of the configuration:

```
if ($request_uri ~ ^(.*/)index\.html($|\?.*)?) {
  return 301 $1$2;
}

location ~* \.html$ {
  expires max;
  add_header "x-ua-compatible" "ie=edge";
  add_header x-frame-options deny;
  add_header x-content-type-options nosniff;
  add_header x-xss-protection "1; mode=block";
  add_header "cache-control" "no-transform";
  access_log logs/static.log;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. It was a matter of re-ordering things.

Here's the working configuration.

```
location ~* \.html$ {
    add_header "x-ua-compatible" "ie=edge";
    add_header x-frame-options deny;
    add_header x-content-type-options nosniff;
    add_header x-xss-protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header "cache-control" "no-transform";
    expires max;
    gzip_static always;
    access_log logs/static.log;
}

location ~* \.(?:html|css|js|txt|xml)$ {
  gzip_static always;
}
```